# Thread not executing twice on clicking a button in onActivityResult()

Tags: android

I have an application that takes picture path from gallery and prints results in main activity.I have a button in `mainactivity()` method and when click a button which is responsible for camera intent the result is called back with `onActivityResult` method.In `onActivityResult()` I created a thread.When application is created after clicking the button the thread is executed but on clicking it other time it is not getting executed.
Let me provide you the code if you won't get my question....
`In MainActivity`

```
thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hello there this isnt displaying twice,Toast.LENGTH_LONG").show();
        }
    });
```

`onCreate() method`

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
```

`onActivityResult() method`

```
Uri selectedimage = data.getData();
            String[] filepathcolumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedimage, filepathcolumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filepathcolumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

            thread.start();
```

What could be the reason?Is there any restriction on thread that should not be started in `onActivityResult()` method.Could this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads only run once. Put your thread creation code in your onActivityResult and it will work.

Comment: Does it run more than once if we pass them to onActivityResult() method

Comment: If this is a question then the answer is no. You have to create a new thread each time (not neccessarily a new runnable). You have to!